# Database query run slow once in a day

Tags: sql-server, indexing, entity-framework-6, query-optimization

I have a production database on SQL Server 2014 Standard edition with ASP.NET using Entity Framework running in a hosted cloud environment.

The problem I am facing is that there are some queries which run slowly (about 10-15 seconds) for the first few times. Then it starts behaving normally and it works perfectly.

Initially I thought it could be a case of parameter sniffing, but upon running profiler for the query when it runs slowly, I found that its doing same no of reads from disk but taking a very long time. For the few number of time the query run slowly. After few runs it works perfectly, reading the same no of reads in very less time(300-700 ms). I also tried running the query first time in SSMS and found that it has same execution plan and reads for slow and faster executions.

This is a one of the queries running slow.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[Alarm] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[AssetID] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[EventCode] IN (1152, 1153, 1154, 1155, 1156, 1157, 1158, 1159, 1160, 1161, 1162, 1163, 1164, 1165, 1166)) AND ([Extent1].[EventCode] IS NOT NULL) AND (((0 = [Extent1].[EventType]) AND (0 = [Extent1].[AlarmStatus])) OR ((0 <> [Extent1].[EventType]) AND (6 <> [Extent1].[AlarmStatus]))) AND (((0 = [Extent1].[EventType]) AND (0 = [Extent1].[AlarmStatus])) OR ((1 = [Extent1].[EventType]) AND ([Extent1].[AcknowledgeDate] IS NULL))) AND (11 <> [Extent1].[AlarmStatus]) AND (12 <> [Extent1].[AlarmStatus]) AND ([Extent1].[SourceID] = @p__linq__1) AND (([Extent1].[SiteID] = @p__linq__2) OR (([Extent1].[SiteID] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__2 IS NULL)))
    )  AS [GroupBy1]',N'@p__linq__0 uniqueidentifier,@p__linq__1 bigint,@p__linq__2 uniqueidentifier',@p__linq__0='B0524A60-F980-4B82-A799-E788A9A4D04B',@p__linq__1=594520350,@p__linq__2='B02A51FE-2248-E611-A64E-782BCB72ACED'
```

[this is execution plan for the query.](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Syqn_I6CG)

I have also tried fetching any slow query execution plan from the plan cache, but there is no slow plan found for the query.

Comment: Probably blocking or some other CPU/IO-intensive operations are on-going (like backup/scheduled jobs). I suggest to use some monitoring tool or run [whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com/) during slow execution

Comment: Actually it can happens on any time when  a specific screen is opened first time, any time in the day, for first few times

Comment: I restored the database on my local machine, sometimes it shows the similar behavior on my local machine too.

Comment: So just check logical vs physical reads. When pages are in buffer cache then the performance is much better. `Logical Reads : Reading Data pages from Cache/Physical Reads : Reading Data pages from Hard Disk`

Comment: does that mean despite the index seeking, its execution plan is poor,  is their any way I can clear buffer cache

Comment: @Rohit, data access is much faster from cache which is why SQL Server strives to keep as much data in memory is possible. The first execution against a cold cache is expected to be slower due to lack of caching. I like to think of SQL Server as an in-memory database that uses storage only for durability and when insufficient memory exists. But your question suggests the second, third, etc. executions are slow too. That might be an issue with warm-up time the way your hosting provider implements your service.

Comment: tried the same query after clearing cache, i can see physical reads and in same number, but reads are are not very high, what causes Sql Server to take so long time to read data from disk

Comment: Check for compilations/recompilations in profiler, also, check the settings for your db, is `OPTIMIZE FOR ADHOC WORKLOADS` on?